# Timer in JQuery to Print a word.. letter by letter

Tags: jquery

How would I make a timer to print the word Loading? By one letter every second?

example: L then another second and then o then another second and then a..

ETC

Comment: This is not related to jQuery. Look into the Javascript function `setTimeout`.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
var msg="Loading";
var index=0;
setInterval(function(){ index++;console.log(msg.substring(0,index)) },1000);
```